# Azure Pipeline: project.assets.json doesn't have a target for 'net48/win7-x64'

Tags: c#, .net, azure-pipelines

I am converting an old application to Azure DevOps, .NET 4.8 and the new project format. Because of some third-parties, I am currently unable to move to net5 or 6. This project generates assemblies in x86 and x64. Both platforms perfectly restore and build locally but I have failures with x64 on Azure DevOps.

```
##[error]C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.404\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(241,5): Error NETSDK1047: Assets file 'D:\a\1\s\src\BraccoUIComponents\obj\project.assets.json' doesn't have a target for 'net48/win7-x64'. Ensure that restore has run and that you have included 'net48' in the TargetFrameworks for your project. You may also need to include 'win7-x64' in your project's RuntimeIdentifiers.
```

I have the following lines in a `Directory.Build.props`:

```
<TargetFramework>net48</TargetFramework>
<RuntimeIdentifiers>win-x64</RuntimeIdentifiers>
<Platforms>x64;x86</Platforms>
```

I have tested the various solutions listed in https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/1321 and the various SO threads but none of them seems to work (`TargetFrameworks`, `RuntimeIdentifier`, `RuntimeIdentifiers`, `win-x64`, `win7-x64`...).

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you have a typo in your "RuntimeIdentifiers" line - it should contain "win7-x64" where you have "win-x64" (note the missing 7).   I see you tried the "win7-64" path as well as some others, I wonder if the time when you tried winy7-64 it actually got through this part correctly and blew up on something else and maybe you misread the tea leaves?

I hit this problem today (on a purely 64-bit application) and my fix was to add this line to all my csproj files:

```
<RuntimeIdentifiers>win7-x64</RuntimeIdentifiers>
```

You might also be missing:

```
<TargetFramework>net48</TargetFramework>
```

My odyssey also included having to root out all the "AnyCPU" configuration items in my solution and projects (using a text editor), as the presence of that configuration in the solution file seemed to override the platform choice I passed to the build task.

I saw other posts around the net that cast suspicion that maybe you were using an old NuGet Restore task, but that didn't apply in my case.

I'm sure you've found a way past this already, but perhaps the next victim of this error message will find this helpful...